# Wrap div around 2 sequential elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have repeating elements like this:

```
<dt class="variationTitle">
  Title
</dt>
<dd class="variationName">
  Name
</dd>
<dt class="variationTitle">
  Title
</dt>
<dd class="variationName">
  Name
</dd>
```

It's a `dt` tag followed by a `dd` tag, unfortunately I can't change the HTML directly, but I need to wrap a `<div class="variation">` around the title and name so it looks like this:

```
<div class="variation">
    <dt class="variationTitle">
      Title
    </dt>
    <dd class="variationName">
      Name
    </dd>
</div>
<div class="variation">
    <dt class="variationTitle">
      Title
    </dt>
    <dd class="variationName">
      Name
    </dd>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option would be to iterative over each `dt` element and then select the adjacent `dd` element and wrap them both using the [`.wrapAll()` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/):

```
$('dt').each(function() {
  $(this).add($(this).next('dd')).wrapAll('<div class="variation"></div>')
});
```

It works because `$(this)` is the current `dt` element, and [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) will add the next `dd` element to the jQuery object, and `.wrapAll()` will wrap each element in the jQuery object.

Comment: `add()` : learned something new. I was assuming it would add something to the selected element, but never guessed it adds an jQuery object to the selected jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var divs = $('dt, dd');
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=2) {
  divs.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<div class='variation'></div>");
}
```

```css
.variation{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dt class="variationTitle">
  Title
</dt>
<dd class="variationName">
  Name
</dd>
<dt class="variationTitle">
  Title
</dt>
<dd class="variationName">
  Name
</dd>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at a computer so can't test this, but I think this will work:

```
  var $set = $('#parentcontainer').children();    
  for(var i=0, len = $set.length; i < len; i+=2){
        $set.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="variation"/>');
  }
```

Hopefully you'll have a parent element wrapping your dt/dd elements.